# Sending and receiving data using 433 Mhz from Arduino to Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, rf, raspberrypi

Following this tutorial: https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/let-raspberry-pis-communicate-with-each-other-per-433mhz-wireless-signals/ I was able to easily send code from one Raspberry Pi Zero to another using a RF 433 MHz Transmissor, Receiver pair using the Ninjablock's 433Utils library.

Now I'm trying to do the same between two Arduinos UNO. I'm following the explanations of the library itself: https://github.com/ninjablocks/433Utils, but until now without success.

> **Arduino_Sketches**
>
> Place the Sketches in your normal Arduino Sketches location. Install
>   any required libraries:
>
> ```
> 1) Servo motor library (Should be included in the Arduino IDE)
> 2) Arduino rc_switch library
> ```

The Arduino rc_switch library is installed in my Arduino IDE.

What I would like to confirm is the following:

While with the Raspberry Pis I go to the folder 433Utils/RPi_utils and type the command `sudo ./RFSniffer` in one terminal and `sudo ./codesend 1234` in another what I have to do with the Arduinos?

Upload the sketch `RF_Sniffer.ino` to one Arduino and the sketch `Send_Demo.ino` to the other and watch in the Serial Monitor the inputs/outputs appearing as magic?

That's unfortunately not working. :-(

May I install anything else? Modules and wiring is OK.

Comment: You should try the sanity check demos.  Do note that cheap 433 MHz receivers are notoriously noisy, but maybe you can see a difference in the LED.  You could also try sending from the Arduino to the pi.  Don't assume the wiring is correct until it works.

Comment: The transmitter and receiver that I use with the Arduinos are the same I used with success with RPis. By the way I've just sent from RPi (./codesend 1234) to the Arduino (using sketch RF_Sniffer.ino) with success. But not yet from Arduino to RPi. I read the code of Send_Demo.ino but I'm not sure what I should do. Just run the sketch and it will automatically transmit a code? Or similar to `./codesend 1234`) should I write something (like `1234`) in the Serial Monitor and hit the send button, so the sketch will transmit that way the code that would be catch by the RF_Sniffer?

Comment: Sounds like you need to study the *code* of whatever sketch you are trying.

Comment: That's what I'm doing and also asking for help. Maybe I find someone that could help by having experience on that.

Comment: The most important thing with making these work with a Uno is to supply enough power.  They simply will refuse to work if only powered by the USB connection.  Recommended to put 9-12 Volts into barrel connector.  How are you powering the Uno?

Comment: Hi @SDsolar With the RPis it worked connected also with the 3.3V pin! But now everything works well with the Arduinos too. As I said above I could already send from RPi and receive with the Arduino. Then I changed the send sketch to use with the Arduino and now I'm able to receive in the other Arduino.